# linux vscode server cant bypass proxy specific domain when i am connect in windows

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

i use vscode ssh connect with linux remote code server
the remote server have proxy `export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:1080` it is ok
but `export no_proxy=github.com` it is bad.
code server extension copilot still use proxy 1080 to connect github.com

when i start up with `code --proxy-bypass-list=github.com` in windows cmd, it is still failed
so, how can i bypass it.

```
Version: 1.76.1 (user setup)
Commit: 5e805b79fcb6ba4c2d23712967df89a089da575b
Date: 2023-03-08T16:32:00.131Z
Electron: 19.1.11
Chromium: 102.0.5005.196
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.26-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
Sandboxed: No
```

[Proxy Support for Extensions should also include NO_PROXY · Issue #68260 · microsoft/vscode · GitHub] (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/68260)

[Setup Visual Studio Code's Network Connection](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/network)

Answer (score 0):

copilot auto detect proxy variable, is not matter with vscode